# Using sudo with other commands

Tags: linux, bash, linux-mint

Suppose I run the command

```
exit
```

Obviously the terminal exits as that is the purpose of the command.

I understand sudo means to run the command with administrator privileges. if I run:

```
sudo exit
```

Then I get "sudo: exit: command not found" from the terminal. Why doesn't the terminal in this case recognize the command and proceed to exit the terminal as it did when ran without sudo?

Comment: `exit` is not a program, it's a shell built-in, you should also try `echo --help` vs `sudo echo --help`. I think `sudo` might only want to execute a program, not a shell built-in

Comment: cross site duplicate : http://askubuntu.com/questions/291666/why-doesnt-sudo-cd-var-named-work

Comment: `sudo` *definitely* wants an executable file.

Comment: Also to add, you can know the type(s) of the command with `type [-a] cmd` e.g. `type -a exit` or `type -a pwd`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most "commands" in a unix-like environment are in fact external programs and scripts.  A few, like `exit`, are actual commands built into the shell.  `sudo` cannot recognize the latter.

From the man page:

> When sudo runs a command, it calls fork(2), sets up the execution
>   environment as described above, and calls the execve system call in
>   the child process.

From the `execve` man page:

> execve() executes the program pointed to by filename.

There is no program named `exit`; it's just a command the shell recognizes.

Think about it this way:  Unix grants permissions to a process.  `sudo` runs a process with elevated/modified permissions.  But when you run `exit` you're not spawning a new process.  `sudo` can't elevate the permissions of the already-running shell; so what would it possibly do?

What you could do is tell `sudo` to spawn another shell, passing `exit` as a command to run that shell... which will do nothing, of course.

Comment: Well, the way to call a shell and have it exit would be `sudo sh -c exit`